# Mysql-front won't open

Tags: mysql, connection, database-connection, web-frontend

After I have updated MySQL-Front, it now does not open its interface, though it asks for which connection to access MySQL Server, but after that, it does not open the interface for Queries. I have re-installed it, but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many ways:

1. Re-installations
2. Installing older versions
3. Deleting MySQL-Front related data from the **AppData** folder
4. Doing all the above and then changing the folder from: ***C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL-Front*** to ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Front\MySQL-Front***